# Function won't execute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function that will execute on a click,  on the condition that a variable is set to 0;

However, the function will not execute, even if the variable is set to 0. 
(I am using jquery)

```
var menuVisible = 0 ;
$('#links').click(function(){ 
    if (menuVisible = 0)
    {
        $('#subMenu').show("slow") ;
        menuVisible = 1 ;
    }
});
```

I'm testing the value of the variable 'MenuVisible' with alert, and it is indeed '0'. So, why won't the function execute ?

Comment: I didn't get alert from SO during editing, I roll it back to your edition, jleedev, because yours better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a suggestion, the solutions offered should have worked.
If indeed you wanted to create a "on click" open/close situation (that is my assumption from your code so don't mind it if it is wrong ) then instead of that variable and hide()/show() you should use the toggle() function. Have fun :)

Answer (score 8):

You're assigning a value with:

```
if (menuVisible = 0)
```

so that will always be false (because it's 0). Change it to:

```
if (menuVisible == 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your `if` statement to:

```
if (menuVisible == 0)
```

The double equals is the equality operator. Single equals is assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can change:

```
if (menuVisible = 0)
```

to:

```
if (!menuVisible)
```

to solve this.